# filling a combo box using value member

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, combobox

consider I have a combo box by following datasource :

```
Value member      Display member
   30001               Red
   30002               Blue
   30003               Green
    ...                ...
```

I can fill My combo box Using Display member for example:

```
ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = ComboBox1.FindString("Blue");
```

But I don't know how can i fill or change my combo box using value member.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: use ComboBox1.SelectedValue = YourValue

Comment: I tried this. but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I think FindString method is used for searching a "string", if your value member is not string data type, you can not use FindString method.

For filling combobox, you can use array.
Ex:

```
int[] ValMember = { 2001, 2002, 2003 };
combo.DataSource = ValMember;
```

SelectedIndex is used for selecting the item based index for show it on combobox.

If you write

```
combo.SelectedIndex = 1;
```

You will get item selected "2002" on combobox, index of array start at zero.

Answer (score -1):

Please using this case

ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = ComboBox1.Items.IndexOf("test1");

I think it's will working in your case